# What makes Windows 10 slow to respond to basic actions?

Tags: windows-10, performance

I own a pretty powerful laptop (Gigabyte Aero 14), equipped with a quad-core Intel i7-6700HQ @ 2.60GHz, upgraded to 32 GB DDR4 RAM, and a Samsung 950 Pro NVMe 512 GB SSD drive. It's also equipped with a GTX 970m GPU.

All in all, I would expect every action I take on this machine to be close to instant. But it's not:

- clicking the explorer icon in the taskbar takes 1 or 2 seconds to open the explorer window
- opening Chrome takes 2 to 3 seconds
- sometimes, I can even "feel" a lag when opening a text file on my desktop in notepad

Boot time is correct (~15s to get to the login screen), but really not as fast as I would expect from this machine, especially with the insane NVMe SSD.

By comparison, my previous laptop was nearly 5 years old (but was in the same price range when I bought it), had a much older processor, less and slower RAM, and a SATA SSD, but felt as fast for everyday use.

I feel like my 5 years newer machine is not really much faster, expect for games where the newer GPU makes a big difference. If it wasn't for the 3D graphics horsepower, it feels a bit like a waste of money to upgrade my PC nowadays.

Why is that? **What keeps Windows 10 from being faster on a faster machine?** How can a simple explorer window take more than 1s to open on a damn fast machine?

*Note that my OS, drivers, and BIOS are all up to date. I use an antivirus software, ESET Nod32, which has a solid reputation for performance. And I was using the same antivirus on my older laptop.*

Comment: I don't have your machine to test this. But others have said that superfetch  sometimes doesn't play nice with SSDs: http://dottoremoe.com/diskfix/  and https://www.technipages.com/windows-enable-disable-superfetch  Looking forward to seeing other responses as I'm not convinced this is the right answer.

Comment: There are many things that can cause that delay. Antivirus ? Likely. Some windows services too (defrag should be off for SSDs).

Comment: disable the Windows Defender. this slows down Windows a lot

Comment: @magicandre1981 Windows Defender is already disabled. It's been disabled by Nod32.

Comment: install Windows Perf tools from Win10 SDK (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk),
 download this profile (https://www.dropbox.com/s/o89gunjrplhnfu2/slowWindowsShell.wprp?dl=0), open cmd.exe as admin, run **wpr -start slowWindowsShell.wprp -start ReferenceSet -fileMode**, capture now the slowness. after you did the slow operations, go back to cmd and run this: **wpr -stop C:\slowWindowsShell.etl** zip the ETL + ngenpdb folder and share it (onedrive). I'll try to analyze what is slow.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, I tried that, but that's a *huge* amount of data collected (550 MB) in just a few seconds, and I have to admit I'm a bit worried to share this data as I'm not comfortable with Windows Perf Tools, and as such I don't know what sensitive data the output may contain...

Comment: I only see names, no content. yes, ETW generates a large amound of data. so don't run it very long. otherwise I can't open it in WPA. upload the zipped ETL to my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/request/EF3lC59C15iK82mkPuaB here only me can see the data

Comment: have you captured the data?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have, but I struggle with the idea of sharing something I have no internal knowledge of. Probably too cautious here, but... that's me :)

Comment: in this case, try to analyze the data for your own (CPU, memory) with WPA: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-154-Memory-Footprint-and-Leaks#time=22m37s. Because you don't share the files, I voted now to close the question as "too broad"